# Constant expressions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

If you have "128 + 7 – i" (where i is declared to be an integer variable), is it a constant expression? Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on where `i` is declared, and whether the compiler can figure out, if there is any chance it can get changed at runtime.

For example, if your code looked like this:

```
...
int i = 3;
int x = 128 + 7 - i;
...
```

the compiler could figure out, that there is no way `i` could change before it was used in your expression. In that case, it could be inlined as a constant expression at compile time.

If, however, it were like this:

```
-(void) doSomething:(int) i {
    ...
    int x = 128 + 7 - i;
    ...
}
```

The value could change at runtime, depending on the method parameter, in which case it could not be constant for the compiler.

Be aware, that whether or not the compiler can do optimizations like the one described above depends on the compiler's settings. For example, in debug builds it would most certainly not do so.

**EDIT**: As correctly pointed out by Rudy Velthuis in the comments, I was a little too fast in my answer. In fact, the first example is not really a constant expression, which the compiler will (very explicitly indeed) tell you. I did not take into account that *constant expression* is a fixed term with a clear definition (e. g. see Java Language Spec [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#5313), don't have a C version handy right now). Instead I confused it with a compiler optimization technique which through data flow analysis inside a method would allow it to replace the aforementioned code with a constant value.

Comment: Try it: `int i = 3; enum { aaa = 128 + 7 - i } test;`. The compiler will tell you that `128 + 7 - i` is not an integer constant expression. IOW, an expression containing a variable is not a constant expression (makes sense, doesn't it?). FWIW, if you declare `const int i = 3;`, the expression is an integer constant expression.

Comment: Damn, you are right. Well, that makes my answer wrong, strictly speaking. However I am quite sure that depending on compiler optimization settings this could be inlined, making this no constant expression, but at least a constant value in the binary. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's not because i is a variable, so, when you do some math with a variable, the result cant be a constant.